# Омыть или вымыть?

Tags: выбор-слова

Есть глагол несовершенного вида "мыть", а в совершенном виде бывают и "омыть", и "вымыть".

Насколько я понимаю, глагол "вымыть" гораздо популярнее, хотя приставка "вы-" обычно обозначает движение из внутренней части чего-либо. Но если же речь идёт именно о мытье посуды, то можно сказать, что она может содержать какую-то еду например, которая при вымывании извлекается. А если речь идёт не о мытье посуды, а о мытье белья, например, или волос, то лучше использовать глагол "омыть"? Я в этом не совсем уверен.

Ищу понятие различия между этими двумя приставками, которые чаще всего находятся перед корнем "мыть".

К тому же, в викисловаре есть и варианты с приставками про-, от-, и по-. Насколько я вижу, их редко используют.

Comment: +1 за самостоятельно написанный текст (не гугло-перевод). (Ошибки есть - исправить?) Вопрос тоже довольно хорош.

Comment: @tum_ Спасибо. Исправить можно! Таким образом, может быть улучшусь.

Comment: Исправил частично, чтобы по-прежнему было очевидно, что писал иностранец. :)

Comment: Someone downvoted the question and the reason might be - it is not crystal clear what exactly you're asking. As I understand your "primary" question here is: "Ищу понятие различия между этими двумя приставками"? (meaning the prefixes *о-* and *вы-*). Correct? BTW, in Russian we would put it as "Пытаюсь понять различие ..."

Comment: *... приставка "вы-" обычно обозначает движение из внутренней части чего-либо.* - [Wiktionary](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/вы-), например, дает три значения. *Вымыть* посути покрывает 1-e и отчасти 3-e, если совсем утрированно, получается что-то навроде "[начать и закончить хорошенько] мыть [всю] посуду".

Comment: Здесь приставка _вы-_ указывает на _результативность_ действия (+ сделать чистым). Устаревшее "омыть" (напр. в религиозных текстах) обозначает действие, лишь _направленное_ на результат. Не стоит придавать универсальное значение какой-либо приставке и конструировать новые смыслы на этой основе.

Comment: I agree that "омыть" is rarely used nowadays, other than, maybe, in some religious texts, but I just wanted to note that it is used in the word "[стеклоомыватель](http://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_2709/5143edfa6f4b285336d9fd339bb80131973bac08/)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

вымыть - to wash completely. вы- indicates completeness here. Вымыть in the sense of moving outside by a stream possibly only used in geology.

омыть - this is a rarely used word, means to put something into water symbolically (for instance, for religious purpose). It does not mean comprehensively washing something. This is of no use unless you perform some religious rite. Literally it means "wash-around". It also can be used in a sense "this island is washed-around by seas".

промыть - I have no idea why you think this is rare. This is not rare but means to wash something inside, like a tube, a hole or mechanism. To make water flow through (**through**-wash).

отмыть - again I have no idea why you think it is rare. It means to wash **of** something. Such as of stain/blot.

помыть - this is the most common word perhaps. It means to wash some amount. The same as вымыть but вымыть stresses the wash is complete (there is nothing left), while помыть may leave something to do later.

also:

- умыть - to wash face
- размыть - to make the contamination spread the surface, also to add blur, also in geology to break rock or something else by continuous stream over long time, make it spread.
- домыть - to continue previously unfinished washing till the end
- смыть - to make the stream to take something from the surface
- подмыть - to wash something from the under (usually refers to washing genitals)
- намыть - to wash until there is substantial result
- обмыть - also to wash around but not symbolically as омыть. Also, to drink alcohol for something.
- смыться - to flee
- взмыть - to fly up, climb

Answer (score 2):

Как раз-таки именно варианты с приставкой *"о-"* сложно встретить в повседневной жизни.
В отличие от вариантов с приставками *"по-"*, *"вы-"*, *"от-"* и *"про-"*.
В частности:

> помыть волосы, вымыть волосы
>   помыть посуду, вымыть посуду, отмыть посуду
>   промыть что-либо под струёй воды

Также широко распространён вариант с приставкой *"у-"* по отношению к лицу:

> умыть лицо

А слово "омыть" лично мне встречается почти только лишь в старых текстах.

Comment: Используется в географии - "Италию омывают пять морей" и т.п.

Comment: "Как раз-таки именно варианты с приставкой "о-" сложно встретить в повседневной жизни" - это сказано во втором предложении самого вопроса (хоть и не совсем гладко). Я так понимаю, суть вопроса - а почему?

Comment: Вымыть и помыть голову,  а не волосы.  И добавьте еще выстирать и постирать белье, не то все так и будут «мыть».

Answer (score 1):

`Омыть` means exactly the same as `вымыть` and those who say that `омыть` does not imply washing are wrong.

The only crucial difference is style, `омыть`does have a very archaic/outdated flavour and is not expected to be used in day by day conversations.

I'd say it can be used to imply an outdated sense on purpose, or in poetry and can be interchangeable with `вымыть`.

`Омывать` however has an additional meaning, which is something like 'to surround with water', in this sense it is still used today and with no archaic connotations: `Берега Италии омываются четыремя морями`.

Answer (score 0):

**Омыть** is being used in modern language only for "wound(s)" and "dead body". Also it possible to "**омыть слезами**" something as a metaphor describing sorrow. Less modern use is for alive body, usually for ritual purpose, before wedding, when baptizing, etc. Also it is used with "legs", what is reference to Bible in general and Jesus Christ and Maria Magdalena in particular. As a whole, this word may by considered as obsolete.